# Ajax-Post-Data-maxJsonLength-property-limit-execeed in javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I am having problem while posting large amount of data from .js file to .cs file via ajax call.

Error is "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property."

```
$http({
    url: exportexcelurl,
    method: 'post',
    data:JSON.stringify({componentid:componentid,city_id:cityid,industrysegment: indsegmentid, wf_activity: wf_activity_id, user: users }),
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
}).success(function (response) {
    var downloadfileurl = webAppBase + "softcopyupload/download";
    window.location = downloadfileurl + '?filename=' + response;
}).error(function (error) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution I found was calling the API in .cs file instead of pushing the data from .js to .cs file. And in .cs file I have set the jsonSerialization object's maxJsonLength to "2147483644". But the same configuration was not working in web.config file